# Convert UTF-16 (wchar_t on Windows) to UTF32

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I have a string of characters given to me by a Windows API function (GetLocaleInfoEx with LOCALE_SLONGDATE) as wchar_t.  Is it correct to say that the value returned from Windows will be UTF-16, and that therefore it may not be one wchar_t, one "printable character"?

To make writing my parser easier, is there a function I can use to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-32, where I'll be guaranteed (I assume), one array element represents one character?

Comment: Perform the conversion yourself, by finding and combining surrogate pairs. Or use a library like iconv.

Comment: Even with UTF-32, you might still have to deal with combining marks in some way or another.

Comment: All Windows compilers use 16-bit `wchar_t` , right? (even gcc ports)

Comment: Oh dear, really?  That seems crazy...

Comment: To add to what @melak47 said. There are two ways to do Unicode correctly. a) treat it as an opaque sequence of bytes, b) handle grapheme clusters. Case (a) handles 99% of apps, because they do little more than string concat. There is never a case where UTF-32 or UTF-16 better represents your data than UTF-8, and vice-versa.

Comment: Let's say I want to find all of the "tokens" in the string representing date format elements such as "yyyy" or "mmm" or "d", for example.  Characters around these can be part sequences, so I can't do a straight up find(L"d") in the string can I, as the "d" may be 0x64 of a multi-element sequence.

Comment: I've always been unclear how well Windows supports UTF-16 compared with UCS-2.

Comment: Unicode is based on the choices made by  typographers.  Who are very sensible people, you have to be when you move around blocks of lead for a living.  Dates strings appeared in printed text frequently, their glyphs take only a single chunk of lead each.  The odds you'll ever have to deal with a glyph that could not be represented in a legacy code page or Unicode version 1 or requires a combining character are zero.

Comment: Ah, thank you Hans.  That was precisely the reassurance I was looking for.  So to conclude, I will almost certainly be Ok with just the UTF-16 string?

Comment: I believe locales can be customized, so you might get absolutely anything.  But by the same token, that makes it impossible for parsing them to be sensible, even if we don't worry about Unicode.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to parse out the format string in order to generate individual UI components for the elements, to make a date/time picker (also rendering any adjoining text in the format).

Answer (score 3):

> where I'll be guaranteed (I assume), one array element represents one character?

That's not how Unicode works. One codepoint (an array element in UTF-32) does not *necessarily* map to a single visible character. Multiple codepoints can combine to form a character thanks to features like Unicode combining characters.

You have to do genuine Unicode analysis if you want to be able to know how many visible characters a Unicode string has.

Even with dates (particularly long-form dates as you asked for), you are not safe from such features. The locale can return arbitrary Unicode strings, so you have no way to know from just the number of codepoints how long a Unicode string is.

Comment: Thanks Nicol.  This is quite disappointing.  So string rendering functions in, say, GDI+ all take this into account too?

Comment: GDI+ maybe (I don't know for sure but I would assume so); DirectWrite yes. This is something usually collectively referred to as "Unicode shaping"; on Windows the low-level Uniscribe library does this directly (but beware that it's incredibly complicated to use).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation for LOCALE_SLONGDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373854(v=vs.85).aspx) it is stated that any characters other than the format pictures must be enclosed in single quotes.  So *in this particular case* converting to UTF-32 should indeed solve your problem (but see proviso below).

By the same token, though, you don't need to.  The only UTF-16 characters that don't represent a single UTF-32 character are the surrogate characters, none of which can be mistaken for a single quote.  So to separate out the format pictures from the surrounding text, you just need to scan the UTF-16 string for single quotes.  (The same is even true of UTF-8; the only byte that looks like a single quote *is* a single quote.)

Any surrogate pairs, combining characters, or other complications should always be safely tucked away inside the substrings thus delimited.  Provided you never attempt to subdivide the substrings themselves, you should be safe.

---

Proviso: the documentation does not indicate whether it is permissible to combine a single quote mark with a combining character in a locale, and if so, how it will be interpreted.  I interpret that as meaning that such a combination is *not* allowed.  In any case, it seems unlikely that Windows itself would go to the trouble of dealing with such an unnecessary complication.  So it should be safe enough to ignore this case too, but YMMV.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks Harry.